# C++: Reference to dynamic memory

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

All considerations about when to use which aside, I am still unsure about pointer vs reference semantics.

Right now, I am under the impression that references are essentially pointers that must be initialized when they are declared, and then from that point on cannot point to anything else. In other words, they are a like a `Type* const` (not `Type const*`), or, they cannot be *reseated*. It essentially becomes a "new name" for that object. Now I heard that references do not actually need to be implemented by the compiler using pointers, but I am under the impression that you can still think of them this way, in regards to what their visible behavior will be.

But why can't you do something like this:

```
int& foo = new int;
```

I want to create a reference to dynamic memory. This does not compile. I get the error

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'
```

That makes sense to me. It seems the new operator returns a pointer of given type to the address of memory that the OS? dynamically allocated for me.

So how do I create a "reference" to dynamic memory?

Edit: Links to resources that precisely explain the difference between references and pointers in C++ would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many correct answers below, but it might be more productive to ask: *why* do you want a reference to dynamic memory? What scenario are you envisioning? (Especially considering that you'll eventually want to release your dynamic memory, and you'll need a pointer to do that.)

Comment: @John Calsbeek I'm asking this so I can better understand what's going on. I can't think of a reason why

Comment: You cannot think of a reason for why you need a reference to a dynamic memory, because probably there is none or exceedingly rare if et all.Just stick to smart pointers and dynamic memory.

Comment: @newprogrammer - To get a good understanding, it is better to look at a reference as an alias, a new name, for something else. That the compiler *sometimes* stores the address of "something else" to remember where to find it, is an implementation detail and not important. The semantics *is* what's important, not the implementation details.

Comment: @Als : Sharptooth below made the comment: "You often need that when you have a pointer and have to call a functon that accepts a reference - that's the same as here." Is this not a valid reason for having a "reference to dynamic memory", so to say?

Comment: @Als : Or maybe you want to write a function which returns a dynamically allocated reference?

Comment: Yes, If you want to modify the addresses pointed to inside the function, then you do need to pass the pointer by reference, this is because if you *pass by value* what you get inside the function is an copy of the original pointer not the pointer itself.If you want to achieve that then yes. it is a valid reason but not that common or user friendly and hence I said rare.

Comment: @newprogrammer In all of these cases you're in exactly the same situation as if you were constructing a reference from a pointer that happens to point to non-dynamic memory (say, the address of a global variable). The crucial difference is with dynamic memory you must be aware of the lifetime issues and take care to free the memory eventually. For example, your hypothetical function that allocates memory and returns a reference to it is sketchy, because if whoever calls that function needs to delete the returned object, then you probably should've returned a pointer in the first place.

Comment: @Als That makes complete sense, thank you.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek So is what you are saying is that returning a reference to dynamically allocated memory is pretty sketchy because it is unusual coding style to return a reference to dynamically allocated memory? (The function caller typically does not expect to have to free that memory later)

Comment: @newprogrammer Precisely. However, if that function had somehow made arrangements to get the memory freed at some later point, then it would make a little bit more sense.

Comment: However, You need to consider carefully @John Calsbeek's suggestion, Reference is just an alias and once you bind it to a pointer,managing the lifetime of the bound pointer becomes your responsibility,and it is not very intutive to do so through an reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, So you need to capture the return value in a pointer.

You can create a reference to a pointer after allocation is done.

```
int *ptr = new int;
int* &ref = ptr;
```

then delete it after use as:

```
delete ref;
```

or more simply,

```
int &ref = *(new int);
```

delete it after use as:

```
delete &ref;
```

Comment: Oh ok, so you can have a reference to a pointer, but you can't just replace the use of the pointer altogether when using `new`?

Comment: @newprogrammer: It can be as in the second case, However, First is always a better choice. It is more intutive and hard to make erros with it.

Comment: This is all making sense now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

References are *syntactic sugar*. They allow one to access an object with the dot operator rather than the arrow.

Your choice of whether to use a pointer or a reference is *semantic*. When you pass an object by reference to a method, or return a reference from a method, you are saying: "This is my object and you may use it, but I own it (and it may be on the stack or the heap.)" It follows that the other answers here which suggest syntax like `delete &foo;` might technically work, but smell bad; If you have a reference to an object then you shouldn't be deleting it. You don't own it and, most importantly, as you can't reset the reference you end up with a reference to deallocated memory, which is *a bad thing*.

Now, if you have allocated an object on the heap (called 'new' to create it) then you do own it, and are responsible for cleaning it up later, so you need to hold a pointer to it. Why? So you can safely delete it later and null-out the pointer.

It follows that the difference between a pointer and a reference, other than the mechanical difference of using dot rather than arrow, is that by passing by reference to a method you indicate something about how an object should be used. To initialise a reference directly by calling new is nonsense, even if possible.

Comment: *"Your choice of whether to use a pointer or a reference is semantic."* You can't pass `nullptr` to a function that takes a reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a reference like this:

```
int& foo = *(new int);
```

In general, to get from `T*` to `T&` you use `*` to "dereference" the pointer.

However this is not a very good idea in the first place. You usually use pointers to store addresses of heap-allocated objects.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `delete &foo`

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Sure it will unless he takes care of the object later.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: You often need that when you have a pointer and have to call a functon that accepts a reference - that's the same as here.

Answer (score 0):

## HOW TO MAKE A REFERENCE TO AN ARRAY

By making an array reference I changed a stack array to become a heap array without extensively rewriting my software. The total changes were three lines of code, in the class declaration, constructor and destructor.

### stack version

```
bool removed [arraySize];
```

### heap version

```
bool(&removed)[arraySize];
Sieve::Sieve() : removed( * (bool(*)[arraySize]) (new bool[arraySize]) )
delete [] (&removed);
```

## Detailed Explanation

Don't be put off by people telling you how to write your software, e.g. saying "Don't do it that way". Their way might be better, but that's a decision you take yourself, and telling you DON'T DO SOMETHING is not an answer to the question "HOW CAN I?", even if what you want to do is bad.

I came here looking for a quick solution to my problem. I had written a Sieve of Eratosthenese program as a benchmark program to test my own prime generator against, and had it working nicely with small numbers to check its operation. I expanded the sieve array size to calculate more prime numbers and had stack size problems, as we might expect. I wanted to replace

```
private:
    bool removed [arraySize];
```

with a simple

```
private:
    bool(&removed)[arraySize];
```

so that the entirety of the working software could continue to work unmodified once I had initialised the `reference` from a `new` statement (in my Sieve class constructor) and of course tidied up with a `delete` (in the class destructor).

I take objection to being told I am too lazy to replace . with -> and should use pointers throughout the software. Being a private member of my class I can access the data without . or -> thank you very much! I do not want to rewrite my member functions accessing the data just because I switch from an array on the stack, to an array on the heap.

So, let's break down what I did to switch from a stack array to a heap array, using an array reference to avoid a major rewite.

```
(new bool[arraySize])
```

That's a fresh pointer to a newly create array for me, on the heap.

```
(bool(*)[arraySize]
```

is the type of the pointer: a pointer to a boolean array of the required size.

To initialize my reference member, I need to do it in the member initialization list of the constructor ...

```
Sieve::Sieve() : removed( ... )
```

where the `...` above is what the reference needs to be initialised to. We are coming to that, so be patient a moment. References are initialized by using the object and the compiler finds it's address. Since we have the pointer, we will need use a `*` to refer to the object found by `new` rather than its address.

So combining the finding the pointer with `new`, converting it to the correct type, and then taking the object it points to, we have

```
* (bool(*)[arraySize]) (new bool[arraySize])
```

and this is what is required in the class member initialization list: the `...` we had above. So all together we have

```
Sieve::Sieve() : removed( * (bool(*)[arraySize]) (new bool[arraySize]) )
```

The opposite is required in the destructor. The array needs to be `delete`d. The way to do that is

```
delete [] ...
```

where `...` is the same pointer value returned by `new`.

In our case it's the address of the reference array

```
(&removed)
```

So we have

```
delete [] (&removed);
```